# In my To do App my edit, save, delete and checkbox button are not firing

Tags: javascript

I am really new to javascript and I have a to-do app to do for a coding Bootcamp project. I need to have the following done:

-create a task with a due date
-edit and delete task
-mark task complete
-sort the task in ascending order
-do a localstorage of the list

Currently, my edit and delete buttons are not working. They are tied to the IDs that are generated to the task ID that is created.

I can't move on until the buttons have been fixed, I am hoping you guys could help,

Is there any more information you need?

You can find the runnable code in the link below:

```js
elements.list.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  const { id } = target.dataset;
  const tasks = id ? document.querySelector('[data-id="${id}"]') : null;
  const sort = document.querySelector(".sort");

  const type = {
    edit: event.target.classList.contains("edit"),
    delete: event.target.classList.contains("delete"),
  };

  const isFromSaveLabel = target.innerText.toLowerCase() === "save";

  if (tasks && type.edit && isFromSaveLabel) {
    const text = task.querySelector("text");
    target.innerText = "Edit";
    text.addAttribute("readonly");
    return;
  }

  if (tasks && type.edit) {
    const text = task.querySelector("text");
    target.innerText = "save";
    text.removeAttribute("readonly");
    text.focus();
    return;
  }

  if (tasks && type.delete) {
    return;
  }
});

const submitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  createTask();
};

elements.form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

https://codepen.io/Blazeinferno92/pen/ExodYON

Comment: Where do you define `id` that's used in `${id}`?

Comment: If this is code for creating each task, you shouldn't repeat the same `id="text"`, `id="date"` in every task. IDs should be unique.

Comment: I updated the code, I created an id function that generates a random Id ```const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}````

Comment: And where do `task` and `date` come from? Some of this code looks like it's the body of the `createTask()` function, but not all of it.

Comment: @FutureCake The code posted doesn't seem to be executable by itself, it's only excerpts.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. It's impossible to tell why it's not working when you put it all together.

Comment: I updated the code, apologies for the long-winded code

Comment: Try making a runnable code example (one of the options in the edit toolbar when editing) as there are probably multiple issues here and things to improve but it's a bit difficult without a runnable example

Comment: I made a runnable code fo you all to take a look https://codepen.io/Blazeinferno92/pen/ExodYON

Comment: When I look at your function that is meant to delete the to-do item (element), it just returns and there is no code that actually does anything?

Also your check to see if an element is a task is returning false when it's actually true. When I change const tasks to true, the functions fire, so the way you're checking if an element is a to-do item could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Harley, when you tested the code did you test it in a different environment or in code pen?